# Unity 4.6 C#: The type or namespace name `IOS' does not exist in the namespace `GooglePlayGames'

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a game developed for iOS as well as android, Here is the code which suddenly started giving an error "Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/PlayGamesClientFactory.cs(31,40): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `IOS' does not exist in the namespace`GooglePlayGames'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
"

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;

namespace GooglePlayGames {
internal class PlayGamesClientFactory {
    internal static IPlayGamesClient GetPlatformPlayGamesClient() {
        if (Application.isEditor) {
            return new GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient();
        }
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        return new GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient();
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
        return new GooglePlayGames.IOS.IOSClient();
#else
        return new GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DummyClient();
#endif
    }
}
}
```

Error is on the line:

```
return new GooglePlayGames.IOS.IOSClient();
```

Comment: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the platform dependent define "UNITY_IPHONE" is marked as Deprecated.
Unity documentation mentions UNITY_IOS as the new PLatform dependent define for the iOS platform.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

The line of GooglePlayGames.IOS.IOSClient(); should be correct. ( not test in my code but the corresponding github archive shows the class in that place.)

Answer (score 0):

Include `using GooglePlayGames.IOS;` at the top of your file.